# Where exactly does trainable_variables method belong in Tensorflow?

Tags: function, tensorflow, methods, loss

I'm a newbie in both deep learning and tensorflow and now trying to learn how to implement deep learning codes based on function API (not keras) by following example codes.
Inside the codes I'm looking at, I found out sources saying 'gradients=tape.gradient(loss,model.trainable variables)'
I intuitionally got what trainable variables mean, however in order to understand clearly,I tried to search on tensorflow documentation (which module or class the method belongs to, which are key arguments, etc) ,but I wasn't able to find the information I want. ('trainable variables' method was not in their documentation index and I'm wondering why)

So can anyone please tell me the module/class which trainable_variable method belongs to, and which arguments it takes, and also how it is able to judge and get all the trainable variables from the model ?

Comment: `model.trainable_variables` returns all the trainable `Variable` present in the model. Here the term "trainable" means the variables which need to be optimized in order to increase the efficiency of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you did not find this method is because `trainable_variables` is not a method, but an attribute/property. The `Model` class has a `trainable_variables` attribute, which is not documented officialy. It is inherited from the base class [`Layer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer), and to put it shortly, the list (of trainable variables) gets populated as new layers are added, since all layers have an init parameter `trainable` (this comes from base class [`Layer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) too). You can check the source code if you want to: "[the source of the property](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L2254)",  "[adding new weights to layer appends to the list](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L628)".